# hide fetched user data from backend

Tags: security, socket.io, request, frontend

I am looking for how to to get user data and expose it in the UI without show it elsewhere in devtools - so I would like that data doesn't appear in any request response.
I considered different possibilities, as cookies or session but none of them allow to hide the data before it is displayed in the UI.

So I wonder what the **usual practice** is and if using socket.io would be considered a hack?

**The idea is:**
User is logged and visits some page, regular API requests are made and serve UI display, and is required user data for UI purposes.

**As an example:**
Are displayed elements to which it is possible to subscribe, so depending of user and of its subscriptions, style is different between followed and unfollowed elements.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the "why" you would want to do that. The normal user doesn't open devtools. The "hacker" user will most certainly not be prevented from getting that data. In the end there're more tools than just the browser's devtools to sniff incoming and outgoing data and since that is something you cannot prevent, there's no reason to do it in the browser in the first place.

What you can do though is encrypting the response in your backend and then decrypt in your frontend. Since you need to send the decryption password as well this will still not prevent anyone from decrypting the response messages, but obfuscating the decryption part somewhere in your code can at least make it a little more difficult (emphasize "little").